# How to override the "swipe from top" gesture on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I'm trying to override the "swipe down from the top of the screen" gesture (the same gesture that opens the Notification Center) in my iOS app.

From my understanding, the correct way to do so is to override the `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()` method on the view controller and use the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to handle the gesture.

In my case, the default system gesture is successfully blocked (Notification Center is not opened, only the gray indicator appears at the top of the screen), but the gesture recognizer is not triggered. Here is the code for the view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
        return .top
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeFromTop))
        gestureRecognizer.edges = .top
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func swipeFromTop() {
        print("swipe from top") // not printed
    }
}
```

I tried the same thing for the "swipe up from the bottom of the screen" gesture and that works as expected (Control Center is not opened and the gesture recognizer is triggered).

I'm testing on iPhone 7 running iOS 11.4.

Comment: You can implement delegate callbacks of `gestureRecognizer` to debug what's going on - e.g. if it receives touches, if it "begins" and if it fails.

Comment: @DisableR thanks for the idea, I tried implementing all of the delegate methods described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate), but none of them are called.

Comment: is your `ViewController` inside of navigation controller?

Comment: @DisableR No, it's just a `UIViewController` in a `UIWindow` (the default setup you get with "Single View App")

Comment: I just created "single view" project and added your code - on iPhone 8 Plus simulator `swipeFromTop` is being called, if I start to swipe a bit below the status bar.

Comment: @DisableR Hm you're right, on the device it also triggers sometimes when the swipe starts a little below the status bar, but it's not very easy to make that swipe. Also I'm not sure if that's the expected behavior behind this gesture recognizer, I'd like it to start even if the swipe begins outside the screen (as it does for showing the notification center)

Comment: That `gestureRecognizer` strangely doesn't receive touches. Actually the `view` is hit tested for the touches that hit status bar. Could be iOS system issue.

Answer (score 1):

To make a "swipe from top" gesture work, you need to hide the status bar by setting your `UIViewController`'s [`prefersStatusBarHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden) property to return `true`.

If your `UIViewController` instance is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, you also need to hide the navigation bar by setting its [`isNavigationBarHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621850-isnavigationbarhidden) property to `true`.

---

The following Swift 5.1 / iOS 13 code sample shows how to implement your `UIViewController` subclass to make the swipe from top gesture work:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        let gestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeFromTop))
        gestureRecognizer.edges = .top
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func swipeFromTop() {
        print("swipe from top")
    }

    override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
        .top
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        true
    }

}
```

---

Sources:

- [useyourloaf.com / Avoiding Conflicts with System Gestures at Screen Edges](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/avoiding-conflicts-with-system-gestures-at-screen-edges/)